# Creating a custom cumulative sum that calculates the downstream quantities given a list of locations and their order

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, math, cumulative-sum

I am trying to come up with some code that will essentially calculate the cumulative value at locations below it.  Taking the cumulative sum almost accomplishes this, but some locations contribute to the same downstream point.  Additionally, the most upstream points (or starting points) will not have any values contributing to them and can remain their starting value in the final cumulative DataFrame.

Let's say I have the following DataFrame for each site.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
"Site 1": np.random.rand(10),
"Site 2": np.random.rand(10),
"Site 3": np.random.rand(10),
"Site 4": np.random.rand(10),
"Site 5": np.random.rand(10)})
```

I also have a table of data that has each site and its corresponding downstream component.

```
df_order = pd.DataFrame({
    "Site 1": Site 3,
    "Site 2": Site 3,
    "Site 3": Site 4,
    "Site 4": Site 5,
    "Site 5": None})
```

I want to do the following:

1)    Sum the values upstream values to get cumulative sum on the respective downstream value.  For instance, Site 1 and Site 2 contribute to the value at Site 3.  So, I want to add Site 1, Site 2, and Site 3 together to get a cumulative value at Site 3.

2)    Now that I have that cumulative value at Site 3, I want to save that cumulative value to Site 3 in "df".  Now I want to propagate that value to Site 4, save it by updating the DataFrame, and then proceed to Site 5.

I can get close-ish using cumsum to get the cumulative value at each site, like this:

```
df = df.cumsum(axis=1)
```

However, this does not take into account that Site 1 and Site 2 are contributing to Site 3, and not each other.

Well, I can solve this manually using:

```
df['Site 3'] = df.loc[:,'Site 1':'Site 3'].sum(axis = 1)
df['Site 4'] = df.loc[:,'Site 3':'Site 4'].sum(axis = 1)
df['Site 5'] = df.loc[:,'Site 4':'Site 5'].sum(axis = 1)
```

However, my actual list of sites is much more extensive and the manual method doesn't automatically take into account the "df_order" provided.  Is there a way to logically link the "df_order" DataFrame in such a way that it can calculate this automatically?  I know how to do this manually, how would I expand this to be able to handle a larger DataFrame and order of sites?

Think of a larger DataFrame, potentially up to 50 sites, that looks like:

```
df_order = pd.DataFrame({
    "Site 1": Site 3,
    "Site 2": Site 3,
    "Site 3": Site 4,
    "Site 4": Site 5,
    "Site 5": Site 8,
    "Site 6": Site 8,
    "Site 7": Site 8,
    "Site 8": Site 9,
    "Site 9": None})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`networkx`](https://pypi.org/project/networkx/) to deal with the relationships. First, make your order DataFrame like:

```
print(df_order)
   source  target
0  Site 1  Site 3
1  Site 2  Site 3
2  Site 3  Site 4
3  Site 4  Site 5
4  Site 5    None
```

---

Create the directed graph

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df_order.dropna(), 
                            source='source', target='target', 
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph)

nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
```

[image]

---

With this directed graph you want to get all of the `predecessors`. We can do this recursively. (Your graph should be a Directed **Acyclic** Graph, otherwise recursion runs into trouble)

```
def all_preds(G, target):
    preds=[target]
    for p in list(G.predecessors(target)):
        preds += all_preds(G, p)
    return preds

#Ex.
all_preds(G, 'Site 4')
['Site 4', 'Site 3', 'Site 1', 'Site 2']
```

And we can now create you downstream sums looping over the columns output by this function for all of your unique Sites.

```
pd.concat([
    df[all_preds(G, target)].sum(1).rename(target)
    for target in df_order['source'].unique()
    ], axis=1)
```

---

Output using `np.random.seed(42)`

```
     Site 1    Site 2    Site 3    Site 4    Site 5
0  0.374540  0.020584  1.006978  1.614522  1.736561
1  0.950714  0.969910  2.060118  2.230642  2.725819
2  0.731994  0.832443  1.856581  1.921633  1.956021
3  0.598658  0.212339  1.177359  2.126245  3.035565
4  0.156019  0.181825  0.793914  1.759546  2.018326
5  0.155995  0.183405  1.124575  1.932972  2.595495
6  0.058084  0.304242  0.562000  0.866613  1.178324
7  0.866176  0.524756  1.905167  2.002839  2.522907
8  0.601115  0.431945  1.625475  2.309708  2.856418
9  0.708073  0.291229  1.045752  1.485905  1.670759
```

Comment: Wow, this is truly awesome!  I did not even know a package like this existed.  Thank you for taking the time and effort to explain how this works and introducing me to a new package.  I  tested this out a small subset of my data and it is working as intended.  It will take a bit longer to get the bulk of my data ready but I will keep you posted!

Comment: C:\Users\jeff\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\unimp_to_dss\lib\site-packages\networkx\drawing\nx_pylab.py:579: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: 
The iterable function was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.1 and will be removed in 3.3. Use np.iterable instead.
  if not cb.iterable(width):
C:\Users\jeff\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\unimp_to_dss\lib\site-packages\networkx\drawing\nx_pylab.py:676: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: 
The iterable function was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.1 and will be removed in 3.3. Use np.iterable instead.
  if cb.iterable(node_size):  # many node sizes

Comment: @JeffColdplume Oh yes so did I. It seems fairly harmless and is something that `networkx` needs to fix not you. The drawing is only for illustration of what's going on, so you can just define `G` and skip that step. Really fun question by the way :D

Comment: That makes sense, thank you again!  I am glad someone was able to understand what I was asking lol.  Usually the hardest part is asking the question in a way others can understand and work off of.

Comment: Hey so this has worked great so far.  I can open up a new question if that works best but is there a way to do this for subtraction?  So something like `pd.concat([
    df[all_preds(G, target)]**.diff()**.rename(target)
    for target in df_order['source'].unique()
    ], axis=1)`.  I realize "diff" does not work in this case but is there an equivalent call  for subtraction that would subtract the sum of the upstream locations from the downstream?

Comment: @JeffColdplume Hmm yes I think that is a bit more involved since in this case both 1 and 2 feed into 3 so it would probably require a bit of logic. I think it warrants a new question (and I also can't spare the time immediately to answer it here).

Comment: No worries, I am also a bit busy right now.  When I do get around to it I will make it a new question.  Thanks!

Comment: Hey man, I uploaded a new question pertaining to subtraction, if you are interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61807858/subtracting-values-based-on-a-relationship-table ;  and if not, no worries!